# HTML combine border of two <a>

Tags: html, css

I have a table with multiple `<a>` elements within:

```css
.TableClass td {
  background-color: #050;
  height: 150px;
}

.TableClass a {
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  border: 5px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="TableClass">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="#"></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p937jbee/1/

Is there a way to avoid double borders?

[image]

UPDATE:
I can't change the HTML code and there are multiple `<td>` instead of 2 of my example.

Comment: I can't believe nobody has mentioned *border-collapse: collapse;* yet.

Comment: @Gordon how does this work? Could you please add this to my fiddle?

Comment: Have a look here https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_border-collapse

Comment: @Gordon I've tried adding it, doesn't work :( could you please help me there?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I haven't decidet which solution I choose, the `border-collapse: collapse;` from gordon seems pretty clean but I can't get it run

Comment: @Toshi As far as I know, Border Collapse won't work w/ your HTML set up and you've stated you can't change your HTML. The collapse has to be applied to the `table` CSS not the `table->td` CSS. Also it won't work with `display:block` you have to use `display:table`; Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ysv6LLc0/1/

Comment: The `border-collapse` trick will only work if you assign the `border` property to the `td` rather than the `a`. Then there is no need for tricks like `display:table`.

Comment: Mr Lister is correct.  I hadn't noticed that you are putting the border on <a>.  I know you can't change the HTML but is there a reason why you want the CSS border on the <a> and not on the <td>?

Comment: @Gordon it's a design issue i have to keep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for multiple cells:

You need to zero out the left border for all cells except first one

```
.TableClass tr td:not(:first-child) a {
  border-left: 0;
}
```

Have a look at snippet

```css
.TableClass td
{
   background-color: #005500;
   height: 150px;
}
.TableClass a
{
 background-color: #ff0000;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 display: block;
 border: 5px solid #000000;
}
.TableClass tr td:not(:first-child) a {
  border-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="TableClass">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
  <td> 
  <a href="#"></a>
  </td>
  <td>
     <a href="#"></a>    
  </td>
  <td> 
  <a href="#"></a>
  </td>
  <td>
     <a href="#"></a>    
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/54o0efuv/

Answer (score 2):

Just add a seperate class to one or both of the boxes where you remove the border ex. [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qq6mwj0h/1/)

```
a.one{
      border-left: 0px;
}
```

html:

```
 <a class="one" href="#"></a>
```

Comment: Is there also a CSS only-solution? I can't change the HTML code

Answer (score 1):

See[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p937jbee/3/)

Add CSS

```
.TableClass td:nth-child(2) a {
 border-left:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work even if you have multiple  elements and not just 2. https://jsfiddle.net/p937jbee/4/

```
.TableClass td
{
   background-color: #005500;
   height: 150px;
}
.TableClass a
{
 background-color: #ff0000;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 display: block;
 border: 4px solid #000000;
}

.TableClass td:first-child a {
  border-right: 2px solid #000000;
}
.TableClass td:last-child a {
  border-left: 2px solid #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a more consistant build-up I suggest to leave the right border, except for the last td. In case you'd like to add more blocks.

**CSS**

```
.TableClass td {
    background-color: #005500;
    height: 150px;
}
.TableClass td a {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    border-right: 0;
}
.TableClass td:last-of-type a {
    border-right: 5px solid #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

use this css

The border-collapse property is for use on  elements (or elements made to behave like a table through display: table or display: inline-table).

Comment: could you please update my fiddle? I can't get this solution run

Comment: Ok that's good but now the green background-color is gone - could you please add this. In my oppinion, that's the cleanest solution

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward method is to assign `border-collapse:collapse` to the table and to move the `border` property from the `a` elements to the `td`s. That is all you need to change.

```css
.TableClass table {
  border-collapse: collapse; /* new */
}

.TableClass td {
  background-color: #005500;
  height: 150px;
  border: 5px solid #000000; /* moved */
}

.TableClass a {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="TableClass">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
  <td> 
  <a href="#"></a>
  </td>
  <td>
     <a href="#"></a>    
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: now the border is around the whole cell instead of the link only but interesting approach, thanks for your reply

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted? In your example, there is no padding around the `a`s, so the borders are in the same place.

Comment: The center border is fine but the top and bottom border doesn't divide the `td` and the `a` anymore

Comment: Ah, you mean in the real page, there is more content in the cells than just the links? I wasn't aware, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

You have to do 2 things, use the nth-of-type on a repeating element, in this case `<td>` and change how you write your brackets. :P  - but really, you may need to say, every 2nd or third block - depending on how you do things. You may want to just use a list instead of a table - depending on the goal. `:nth-of-type(2n+2)` etc. Look her up. : )

### HTML

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table">
  <tr>
    <td> 
      <a href="#"></a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#"></a>    
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### CSS

```
.table a {
  background: #ff0000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  border: 4px solid #000000;
}

.table td:nth-of-type(odd) a {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}

.table td:nth-of-type(even) a {
  border-left: 2px solid black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6bgbmde5/

or you can use the background of the `tr`

```
.table tr {
  display: block;
  background: black;
  padding: 4px;
}

.table a {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}

.table td:not(:last-of-type) a {
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

There are many ways that all have side-effects and it all depends on hovers and all sorts of stuff. Good luck!

Comment: Is there also a way to make this work for multiple `<td>`? https://jsfiddle.net/6bgbmde5/1/

Comment: I'd recommend against changing the border width to achieve a solution. OP wants a border width of 5 not 4. Also this fails if the HTML has more than two anchors. https://jsfiddle.net/nt23Lokt/1/

Comment: My other fiddles show the various ways to deal with any number of boxes. I don't really want to argue about it. This is my answer. There are plenty of answers to choose from.

Comment: @sheriffderek you know what you're right, arguing over answers isn't really in the spirit of this site. I'm sorry

Comment: If there was an :emogi-hug, I'd put it here.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.TableClass td
{
   background-color: #005500;
   height: 150px;
}
.TableClass a
{
 background-color: #ff0000;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 display: block;
 
}

.elem1{
  border-top: 5px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000000;
  border-left: 5px solid #000000;
  }
  
  .elem2{
  border-top: 5px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000000;
  border-left: 5px solid #000000;
  border-right: 5px solid #000000;
  }
```

```html
<div class="TableClass">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<td> 
<a href="#" class="elem1"></a>
</td>
<td>
   <a href="#" class="elem2"></a>    
</td>
</table>
</div>
```

here is an updated fiddle, hopefully with be a solution for you

Comment: Is there also a CSS only-solution? I can't change the HTML code

Comment: you can look into the solution provided by Banzay for css only

Answer (score 0):

Since OP has stated that they can-not change the HTML a hacky CSS solution must be implemented. Therefor I will use negative margins which many of you frown upon but I don't see any other options available.

Use the following CSS:

```css
.TableClass td {
   background-color: #005500;
   height: 150px;
}
.TableClass a {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    margin-left:-5px;
}
.TableClass td:nth-child(1) a {
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Why are you posting the same answer twice?

Comment: @MrLister They aren't the same answer, in the first one I applied -5 margin to all `a` then increasing background size by 5px manually. In this version I apply a -5 margin to only the a's that aren't the first a and no manual increase in background size is required. I left the old one up at first because I thought OP may be using it and I didn't want to delete it while OP was studying it, though this is a more complete and in my mind, different, answer. Thanks for bringing this to my attention as I can now go delete the other one since I know OP has now seen both.

Comment: I fail to see the point. Even if the OP could change the html, you would still need to style the border with CSS. This is nonsense.

Comment: I appreciate your solution, but I would only use negative margins as a last resort.

Comment: @sheriffderek as I have

Comment: As an answer - this is your first resort.